# Unexpected result of a substitution inside a function argument

Tags: sympy

```
In [4]: from sympy import pi, sin, solve, symbols
   ...: t, w0 = symbols('t omega_0')
   ...: wb = 6*w0
   ...: f = sin(wb*t)
   ...: display(f)
   ...: t1 = solve(wb*t-pi, t)
   ...: display(t1)
   ...: f1 = f.subs({t:t1})
   ...: display(f1)
sin(6*omega_0*t)
[pi/(6*omega_0)]
sin(6*omega_0*t)
```

I expected that the value of the substitution, because there are no more free variables, would be `sin(pi)` or, even better, `0`.
Obviously I'm missing something...

---

As exposed by [Oscar Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9450991/oscar-benjamin) in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73593856/2749397) `t1` is a list — as a matter of fact, I need a coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get an error when I run this code with the latest version of SymPy:

```
In [4]: f
Out[4]: sin(6⋅ω₀⋅t)

In [5]: t1 = solve(wb*t-pi, t)

In [6]: t1
Out[6]: 
⎡ π  ⎤
⎢────⎥
⎣6⋅ω₀⎦

In [7]: f1 = f.subs({t:t1})
...
SympifyError: [pi/(6*omega_0)]
```

That's because `t1` is a list. Note that a list is returned because in general an equation to be solved can have more than one solution. You should substitute `t` for the *item in the list* which you can refer to as `t1[0]`:

```
In [8]: f1 = f.subs({t:t1[0]})

In [9]: f1
Out[9]: 0
```

Alternatively I recommend using `solve` with the `dict=True` argument so that it always returns a list of dicts. Each dict can be used directly with `subs`:

```
In [10]: t1 = solve(wb*t-pi, t, dict=True)

In [11]: t1
Out[11]: 
⎡⎧    π  ⎫⎤
⎢⎨t: ────⎬⎥
⎣⎩   6⋅ω₀⎭⎦

In [12]: f.subs(t1[0])
Out[12]: 0
```

Comment: I am on Python 3.9 and Sympy 1.10.1,  no Exception raised… So it goes.

Comment: I realise actually I was using the master branch of SymPy. The fix (to raise an error) will be in the next release: 1.12. I had forgotten that I actually fixed that bug myself: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/23887